# ExternalSignInAsync - when does it return SignInStatus.RequiresVerification?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using the standard MVC template from VS 2013 and using logins with External Ids, ie Google, Facebook, etc.

In `AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback`, it calls `SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync` and the result can be one of SignInStatus`.Success`, `.LockedOut`, `.RequiresVerification`, and `.Failure`.

I have been able to make it return `LockedOut` by putting a time later than now in column `LockoutEndDateUtc` of `dbo.AspNetUsers`.

When or how does it return `RequiresVerification`?

I want to use this identity framework but with a bit of customization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Two-Factor Authentication, then login will return `SignInStatus.RequiresVerification` for the user to enter the verification code.

See [Two-factor authentication using SMS and email with ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity)

Comment: What does "using Two-Factor Authentication" exactly mean?
I set a users "TwoFactorEnabled" value as true but still it's not returning RequiresVerification

Answer (score -1):

ExternalSignInAsync return RequiresVerification if :

dbo.ASpnetUsers has for user set to true TwoFactorEnabled and EmailConfirmed and user email should be confirmed, email not be empty or null.